# How to make stock fonts available offline in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, fonts, local, offline, aframe

I'm trying to make stock fonts available offline in A-Frame. I have already try to download all the files from [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/text.html#stock-fonts) and linked it using this this code:

```
<html>


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-text value="This is the text" font="Roboto-msdf.json"></a-text>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Is there a more empirical way to just change the link to font and make everything work as default?**

This is the explanation from the A-Frame website: *"Select from one of A-Frame’s built-in fonts. These fonts will be loaded in from over a CDN. If you want your application to work better offline, download these fonts locally and point to them via a URL."*

I don't understand what it means with **download these font locally and point to them via a URL.** especially to make the default (Roboto) change to font available in my server, Can anybody helps?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to serve the fonts through a [Web Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). Browsers cannot access files in your machine directly. You then need to point the font to the URL as described in the docs:

```
<a-entity text="font: http://localhost:port/fontname.fnt; value: Via URL."></a-entity>
```

Comment: How can I set it for default font? So, I can use it just like this : <a-text>The font change!</a-text> for all a-text